# Why do function prototypes include parameter names when they're not required?

Tags: c++, naming, function-prototypes

I always thought that a function prototype must contain the parameters of the function and their names. However, I just tried this out:

```
int add(int,int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << add(3,1) << std::endl;
}

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

And it worked! I even tried compiling with extreme over-caution:

```
g++ -W -Wall -Werror -pedantic test.cpp
```

And it still worked. So my question is, if you don't need parameter names in function prototypes, why is it so common to do so? Is there any purpose to this? Does it have something to do with the signature of the function?

Comment: I think the readability would be much better if parameter name is included in the prototype.

Comment: How exactly does it add to readability?

Comment: in your case you have two `int` parameters, without the names how does one know whether to pass in `x` first or `y`?

Comment: In functions that have obscure parameter names(like x and y), how does it do any difference to write them in the prototype?

Comment: The order of the parameters in your `add` function are not important, and most people already know that a function named "add" would add its parameters together without applying meaning to the values, so the names aren't really important in this example. But consider a function like `strstr`. The order is important. Which parameter comes first? Wouldn't it be easier to remember if the parameters had distinctive names, such as `needle` and `haystack`, and if your editor would show those names to you while you wrote your code or when it reported errors? *That's* readability.

Comment: x and y could be good enough for some simple function, such as add(x, y), but they are not good variable name for some non-trivial function. For example, the prototype declares a parameter as int, and names it as BufferSize, you know what to pass to it. If there is no name, it is a little hard to pass the right parameter to the function, especially the implementation is hide from the caller.

Comment: Is this valid even for C or just C++?

Comment: In C only for declarations, function definitions require named parameters.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, these are not necessary, and are mostly ignored by the compiler. You can even give them different names in different declarations; the following is entirely legal:

```
int foo(int bar);
int foo(int biz);
int foo(int qux) {
    ...
}
```

(The compiler does check that each name is used only once in the same argument list: `int foo(int bar, int bar);` is rejected.)

The reason to put them in is documentation:

- If someone reads your header file, they can tell at a glance what each parameter is used for.
- If you use a fancy IDE, it can show you the parameter names when you begin typing the function call.
- Documentation tools like Doxygen can parse the parameter names and show them in the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

Parameter names are completely optional, and have no effect on compilation. They may be placed there for better readability of code.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need parameter names in declarations. They are purely documentation.

You don't even need names in definitions:

```
int f(int)
{
    return 0;
}
```

compiles just fine in C++ (though not in C). This is sometimes useful for e.g. inheritance, overloading, function pointers.

Comment: If you make such a function, without specifying the name of the parameter, how do you access it? If you can't access it, then why make it at first place?

Comment: You do need the names in the definition if the definition uses that parameter.

Comment: You can't access it. You might put it in in at least two situations: (1) for forwards compatibility, in case you want to start using it later without having to update all call sites; (2) when you override a virtual method, but don't want to inspect the argument.

Comment: @MisterSir: you can't access the parameter if it doesn't have a name. You'd only use this if the parameter is needed to conform to an interface, but is not actually used. I personally like this style better than using names such as `unused1` etc.

Comment: Omitting the name of an unused parameter in the definition also often has the effect of suppressing any "unused parameter" warnings from the compiler.

Comment: @MisterSir: There are situations when you have a parameter which you don't actually use. It is used for overload resolution only.For example, see std::advance function. If you name the parameter, you'll get a warning

Comment: @MisterSir on some occasions you don't want to access it, in particular our old friend iterator::operator++(int) where the int is only there to indicate that it is a post-increment operator.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to include parameter names in function prototypes.  You only need the complete signature, which includes the types of parameters and (in the case of function template specializations) return values.

However, it is still common to include parameter names in order to write self-documenting code.  That is, a function with this declaration:

```
void foo(int number_of_foos_desired, string foo_replacement);
```

is easier to understand by looking only at the prototype, perhaps, than this one:

```
void foo(int, string);
```

Many modern IDEs will also pop up the parameter names as you type when you write code that calls this function.  They may not be able to pop up this information if you dont include the parameter names in the prototype.

Comment: I always thought a function signature doesn't include its return type(unless it's a template specialization)

Comment: @Mister:  Generally this is true.  But int he case of specializations of function teplates, the return type is part of the signature.

Answer (score 1):

It has alot to do with the signature of the function.

One of the benefits of using .h files is that when someone comes along and wants to get a sense of what your program/api does, they can look at your header file and get a sense of what operations are being carried out, their inputs and outputs, how everything is going together, etc.

If you were to come across a method like

```
int doStuff(int,int)
```

this would be alot less telling than a method with a signature of say:

```
int doStuff(int firstNumberToAdd, int secondNumberToAdd);
```

with the second, you at least get some idea of the operations that are being carried out, and what is happening. This is the idea behind writing self documenting code.

If your interested, you may check out Code Complete by Steve McConnell.

Comment: The parameter names are not part of the signature.

Answer (score 1):

There are different scenarios to it. I found it very helpful in dealing with `inheritance` and `virtual functions`. If you're using a `virtual function` that generates unused warning in sub class, you can omit the variable names.